# Is there any way to modify value in properties of anonymous object?

Tags: c#, .net, anonymous-types

Here my simplified code:

```
var responseObj = new
{
    memo = ""
};
responseObj.memo = "Test";
```

As you can see, I tried to modify `responseObj.memo`, but the result:

[image]

Is there any other way for it?

Comment: @DavidG Oh okay then thanks.

Comment: Also, these are called anonymous, not local in C#

Comment: Thanks for the remark, I'm gonna edit my question then.

Answer (score 1):

Anonymous type based classes are read only. You will have to create your own class in order to write back to the member.

```
class MyClass
{
    public string Memo { get; set; }
}
```